# Setting random element to a variable in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to make a game where you press the back of a card, it displays a random card and then removes that card from the card deck array. When I simulate the program it runs for a random amount of times and then gives me the Index out of range error.

Does anyone see where I have done something wrong?

```
var cardDeck = [card1, card2, card3 etc....]

var randomCard: Int = 0




@IBAction func row1card5tap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    randomCard = Int.random(in: 0...51)

    if cardDeck.contains(cardDeck[randomCard]) {
        row1card5.image = cardDeck[randomCard+1]
        cardDeck.remove(at: randomCard)

        print("removed:" + "\(cardDeck[randomCard])")
    } else {
        print("card already removed")
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you get it when you try to subscript the cardDeck array with 52 by adding 1 to random number. You can do 0..<51 to avoid that

Comment: thanks for the reply. i tried changing 0...51 to 0..<51 but i still get the out of range error

Comment: So your cardDeck array is dynamically created. I thought it always consists of 52 cards. It's very normal to get out of range error in that case. You should make sure the array count is bigger than the requestedIndex + 1 before subscripting

Comment: @OkhanOkbay would you be able to help me out, how should the code look? Im not very experienced im afraid

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure the array count is bigger than the requestedIndex + 1 before subscripting

```
 var cardDeck = [card1, card2, card3 etc....]

 var randomCard: Int = 0

 @IBAction func row1card5tap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

   randomCard = Int.random(in: 0...51)

   if cardDeck.count > randomCard + 1 {
     row1card5.image = cardDeck[randomCard+1]
     cardDeck.remove(at: randomCard)

     print("removed:" + "\(cardDeck[randomCard])")
   } else {
     print("card already removed")
   }
 }
```

Comment: thank you so much!! works perfectly now. however I get an yellow warning, saying "Left side of nil coalescing operator '??' has non-optional type 'Int', so the right side is never used". should I care about it?

Comment: I wrote the code on SO, I dunno why I thought count returns as an Optional :) Edited the answer now

Answer (score 1):

If you want

> it displays a random card and then removes that card from the card deck array

then the upper bound of the random array should be always the current number of cards in the deck

```
var cardDeck = [card1, card2, card3 etc....]

@IBAction func row1card5tap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if cardDeck.isEmpty { return }
    let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0..<cardDeck.count)
    row1card5.image = cardDeck[randomIndex]
    cardDeck.remove(at: randomIndex)
}
```